How to exclude some libraries to be trimmed in .NET 8 for Android, not MAUI?
I'm migrating my app from Xamarin.Android to .NET 8 and I'm getting some issues since I don't have an option to exclude some libs that existed in Xamarin:

But in .NET 8 for Android in Visual Studio 2022, there is nothing like that:

I tried to add some code like this one in the .csproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
  <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
  <AndroidKeyStore>False</AndroidKeyStore>
  <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
  <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
  <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
  <AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
  <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
  <AndroidKeyStore>False</AndroidKeyStore>
  <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
  <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Xamarin-MaterialSearchBar" RootMode="CopyUsed" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Xamarin-MaterialSearchBar" RootMode="CopyUsed" />
</ItemGroup>

Or like this:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
  <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
  <AndroidKeyStore>False</AndroidKeyStore>
  <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
  <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
  <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
  <AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
  <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
  <AndroidKeyStore>False</AndroidKeyStore>
  <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
  <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Xamarin-MaterialSearchBar" />
</ItemGroup>

And I got error like these ones:

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4096 The item "Xamarin-MaterialSearchBar" in item list "TrimmerRootAssembly" does not define a value for metadata "RootMode"


Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IL1037  Invalid assembly root mode 'CopyUsed'.


Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1144  Optimizing assemblies for size failed. Optimization can be disabled by setting the PublishTrimmed property to false.

Without the trimming, my app increases almost twice its size. Any idea how can I exclude this library?
